# SQL Query - Replace text by text if a condition is verified

Tags: mysql, sql

I have more than 3000 correction to do.

My database has a table named `ps_product_lang`,
inside the table `ps_product_lang` I have one column called `link_rewrite` and one column called `description_short`.

In the column `link_rewrite` I want to replace this expression `rask-usb-billader` by this `rask-usb-lader` only if the `description_short` column contains "

Rask USB lader eksklusivt" if not then do not replace.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query:

```
update ps_product_lang
set link_rewrite = replace(link_rewrite,'rask-usb-billader','rask-usb-lader')
Where 
description_short like '%Rask USB lader eksklusivt%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query.

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN ps.description_short="Rask USB lader eksklusivt"
    THEN "rask-usb-lader" else ps.link_rewrite END AS link_rewrite
    FROM ps_product_lang ps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update ps_product_lang
set link_rewrite = case when link_rewrite = 'rask-usb-billader' and description_short = 'Rask USB lader eksklusivt' then 'rask-usb-lader'
                        else link_rewrite
                   end;
```

If you are using MySQL workbench make sure you disable safe mode which enables updates without `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
update ps_product_lang
set link_rewrite = 'rask-usb-lader'
Where 
link_rewrite = 'rask-usb-billader' and 
description_short = 'Rask USB lader eksklusivt'
```